# Translating logic into Kotlin (or Java) code

Tags: java, kotlin, parsing

I have a use-case where I want to enable users to write simple logic, and behind the scenes, convert this logic into a condition in the code.

For example, the user might write:

```
someFieldName > 10 AND otherFieldName is NULL
```

And I'd like that to generate the following code:

```kotlin
if (data["someFieldName"] > 10 && data["otherFieldName"] == null) {
   // Do something
}
```

After doing some research, I saw that one of the options is using eval (by leveraging a JS engine), although it doesn't fit all use cases.
I also saw that it's possible to use tools like ANTLR, which seems a bit like overkill.

Are there any simple off-the-shelf products we can use for such purposes? Or would creating a simple parser ourselves be the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case can be adequately addressed by [MVEL2](http://mvel.documentnode.com/).

There is no need for you to write a parser and AST with ANTLR or convert to Java code, just evaluate the expression with appropriate parameters.

In fact any Java expression language library would do. You could also look at [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/).

However, looking at the expression, I would say it aligns more towards MVEL2.

Give both the libraries a try.

Comment: I'm wondering, after looking into these libraries, they seem functionally equivalent to JS engines running on Java (like Java Nashorn). At least for the use case of evaluating String expressions (which is my use case, translating configuration/simple user input into conditional expressions at runtime).

Am I missing something? or are they indeed roughly equivalent (the JS engine and libraries) for such use cases?

Comment: Yes, for your use case, they would work the same. JS is more of a language and therefore is more powerful than EL. However, in JS users can potentially write arbitrary code and upload to your application. ELs from that perspective is safer, they constrain the features that can be used and only on the data supplied (which is under your control). It is best not to allow users to upload JS code (code could be malicious). EL expressions are merely string parsed and evaluated on the data in a constrained environment, though there are EL injection attacks as well, they are in a different context

Comment: Thanks!
For my specific use case, users wouldn't be able to format the code as they wish, it's more of a managed configuration as part of an internal app, so I'm not too worried about malicious attacks.